# Creating a table but with other entities in a compound key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 Primary key tables and 1 Compound table.

I want to have some other information apart from the 2 primary keys from the primary key table in the compound table.

Would I just repeat this data or is their a way to add other fields into a the compound field without repeating it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current design looks close to right.  But I think your `EventVolunteer` table should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE EventVolunteer (
    eventID INTEGER,
    volunteerID INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY eventID REFERENCES Event(eventID),
    FOREIGN KEY volunteerID REFERENCES Volunteer(volunteerID),
    PRIMARY_KEY(eventID, volunteerID)
)
```

This bridge table should exist to store relationships between events and their volunteers, and nothing else.  All metadata for events and volunteers should be in the `Event` and `Volunteer` tables, respectively.

If you need to bring in some information, then you can do so via joining the `Event` and `Volunteer` tables with this bridge table.  This join is much less of a penalty than you might think, if you have indices setup in the right places.

Comment: Thank you, so the bridge table should not include any fname or lnames?

Comment: So the information such as lName and fName should only be retrieved by doing a query for example, and should not go into the bridge table?

Comment: The names belong in the `Volunteer` table.

Comment: I have another question posted below, could you have a look please?